# TypeORM Update All Records Part Of A Mant-to-Many Relation

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a many to many relationship between `Channel` and `User` which is used to send email notifications to users subscribed to a channel. I'm developing a feature where one channel is dissolved in favor of another but I don't know how to transfer all notifications from the dissolving channel to the target channel.

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date

    @Column()
    updatedAt: Date

    @Column()
    email: string

    @ManyToMany(_type => Channel)
    @JoinTable()
    notifications: Channel[]
}

@Entity()
export class Channel {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date

    @Column()
    updatedAt: Date
}

async function transferNotifications(from: unknown, to: unknown): Promise<void> {
    //?
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two options you have:

**1. Working with EntityManager**

First, fetch all `User` entities with the resolved relation to `notification`. Then delete the old (dissolved) `Channel` entity from the `notification` property of all fetched `User` entities and add the new `Channel` entity to that array if it previously contained the old one. That will remove the corresponding join table row and add a new one to the new channel.

The obviously drawback is, that a join will be executed over three tables on all rows with all results get loaded into application memory. So not necessarily a good solution for larger tables.

**2. Working with QueryBuilder**

A better approach would be to build up the join table yourself by adding a custom join table entity. Then use `QueryBuilder` to replace the old foreign key to the old channel with the id of the new one.

```ts
getRepository(UserChannel).createQueryBuilder()
   .update()
   .set({ channelId: '<new channel id>' })
   .where(`channelId = :channelId`, { channelId: `<old channel id>`})
   .execute();
```

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date

    @Column()
    updatedAt: Date

    @Column()
    email: string

    @OneToMany(type => UserChannel)
    userChannels: UserChannel[]
}

@Entity()
export class UserChannel {

    @ManyToOne(type => User)
    user!: User;

    @Column({ primary: true })
    userId!: string;


    @ManyToOne(type => Channel)
    channel!: channel;

    @Column({ primary: true })
    channelId!: string;
}


@Entity()
export class Channel {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: string

    @Column()
    createdAt: Date

    @Column()
    updatedAt: Date
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will pursue option number two. As mentioned its possible for a channel to have many notifications and loading them all into memory wouldnt be a good idea. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using NodeJs. You could use promises for bulk update, delete or anything else.

What you need to do is `map` all the updates to array and then resolve them using `Promise.all`.

New updates.

```
updates = [{ id: 1, name: "Channel 1" }, { id: 2, name: "Channel 2"}];
```

Bulk update code

l

```
let promises = updates.map(update =>  { 
      let query = {id: update.id};
          delete update.id;
          return channelRepository
              .update({id update.id}, update) 
         });
return await Promise.all(promises);
```